# Node Async / Await issue

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

So I am porting my slackbot from python over to Node and am having issues with async/await.
My function is completely ignoring the await keyword and the linter is giving me the following error:

***'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.***

Here is the code:

```
function list_channels(access_token) {
  fetch(`https://slack.com/api/channels.list?token=${access_token}`)
    .then((r) => {
      r.json()
      .then(c => {
        let channels = {}
        for (channel of c.channels) {
          channels[channel.name] = channel.id
        }
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          console.log("_______resolve", channels)
          resolve(channels)
        })
      })
    })

}

const wrapper = {
  list_channels: list_channels
}
module.exports = wrapper
```

and

```
  app.get('/admin', async (req, res) => {
    const user = req.user
    let a = await wrapper.list_channels(code)
    res.send({hmm:a})
  })
```

When I call the route, I get `{}`

Comment: You're not returning anything from list_channels, so it returns `undefined` and `await undefined` is just `undefined`. You should `return fetch(...` to fix it. You also don't need the inner Promise at all, just `return channels;` instead of `return new Promise`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks guys. I realized this after waking up today. Guess I had been mentally exhausted yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code keeping the var/function names (Although you should use better names)

```
async function list_channels(access_token) {
    let r = await fetch(`https://slack.com/api/channels.list?token=${access_token}`);
    let c = await r.json();
    let channels = {}
    for (channel of c.channels) {
        channels[channel.name] = channel.id;
    }
    console.log("_______resolve", channels);
    return channels;
}

module.exports = {list_channels} // Object with property list_channels
```

As you can see, you can use `await` instead using `.then`. Like that, you will avoid the **callback hell** problem, making you code more readable and easy to edit.

There is a nice explanation here: http://callbackhell.com/

---

If you really want to go on **callback hell way**, you can do something like:

```
function list_channels(access_token) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fetch(`https://slack.com/api/channels.list?token=${access_token}`).then((r) => {
            r.json().then(c => {
                let channels = {}
                for (channel of c.channels) {
                    channels[channel.name] = channel.id
                }
                console.log("_______resolve", channels)
                resolve(channels)
            })
        })
    })   
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So just to be clear in your re-written Async/await part, we are just not returning something until await resolves? 
Lol i do need better names. I was just testing this because I wasn't confident with how things should be done.Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, `await` waits the returned promise be resolved **and extracts the value resolved by the promise**. It have the same effect of using callbacks, but makes the life easier (Also called **syntactic sugar**).

Comment: What I mean with **"and extracts the value resolved by the promise"**: https://jsfiddle.net/alanvncs/9tjpb82w/18/